# How to remove WP Title Tag?

Tags: theme-development, custom-header

I have addded a custom title tag for a custom post type in `header.php` like follows

```
if(is_singular( 'news' )){
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo '<title>'. get_the_title() .' of '. strip_tags(get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'genre', '', ' ', '' )) .' read online</title>';
}
```

This code works fine but I just do not know how to remove default the WordPress title tag. So now all my single news post have 2 title tags. One is above the source code and one is WordPress's default title tag. How can I disable WP title tag for single news? The one that comes with `wp_head()` ?

Comment: You have a typo in the echo, </title instead of </title>

Answer (score 1):

The default `<title>` can be handled by a template as a direct input in `header.php` or by the theme setup or options screen in backend.

If your theme won't show up `<title>` tag in the `header.php`, then it's pretty likely than the `functions.php` file has something like this:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

You can remove that line and it won't print the `title` tag in `head`, so you can do it manually.